# jQuery mouseenter/ mouseeout effect - not with first hover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, fadein, mouseleave, fadeout

I thought it would be easy - make simple hover effect with jQuery. But I have strange behaviour with this code:

```
jQuery('.has-children').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
          jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').fadeIn();
      },
    mouseleave: function () {
          jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').fadeOut();
      }
});
```

full code: http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/R5qnt/2/

First time after loading the page hover effect is without fade, just plain css hover. Next one is finally with jQuery fade. Anyone can explain it to me?

**UPDATE**

I also tried with jQuery .hover() and .fadeToggle(); but it behaves strange as well and works contrariwise: mosueenter is hidding .sub-menu and mouseleave is revealing content :-/

```
jQuery('.has-children').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('.sub-menu').stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
});
```

full code: http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/R5qnt/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS has `:hover` which sets `display: block`. This means you need to call `hide()` first on the collection.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwujj/).

Comment: Just be curious - if this solution can be applied to second code (with .hover()) - ok, it can be: http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/R5qnt/9/